# Storing additional data in Entities

Tags: nhibernate, entity, dto

Let's say I have the following Entities: `Location` & `Product`

`Locations` have dimensions (length, width, height) and so do `Products`.  `Locations` contain one or more `Products`.  Basically I need to get a bunch of `Locations` and calculate based on their dimensions and `Products` at the `Location` the remaining room left at a particular location.  I need to basically store this value (the amount of room left) and sort the `Locations` based on this value.

**Where should I store this value?**

**Should I store it in the `Location` entity itself as just a property that is not mapped to anything in the database?**  This seems like it is bad practice but easy to do.

**Should I create a DTO for this that contains this additional property and the rest of the location data (this kind of seems like a lot of extra work for this scenario)**?

**Should I maybe create a wrapper basically that has this one additional property and the actual `Location` entity inside it?**

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that the data is intrinsic to the object itself so I think it is entirely appropriate to add it to Location class.

I would simply make this a lazy property on the Location class. It should only be computed when required and presumably might trigger lazy loading of the Location's collection of Products.

If you want to you can map it to a table column so when NHibernate is flushing it will always write out the most up to date value. This will then enable you to use it in queries for ordering and filtering at the db level.